# Replacing SRAM Apex 1x with Shimano GRX 1x

Tags: shimano, crankset, compatibility, sram, road

I have a SCOTT GRAVEL Expert with SRAM APEX 1x10 crankset. The crank is similar to [this bike](https://www.cycleexchange.co.uk/products/copy-of-specialized-diverge-base-carbon-sram-apex-1-gravel-bike-2021-size-54cm).

I've been looking for a GXP power meter but they are difficult to find in both the used market and new, well they cost upwards of 500USD which is something that I don't want to invest. I already have Assioma DUO PM pedals on my road bike, but I will be training on sub-zero temperatures with a good amount of snow and sleet, and there are just not many options at all for winter boots with road clips.

Cheaper Stages and 4iiii however exist on the used market and one can even find offers online with 50% discounts.

I was therefore planning to swap my APEX 1x with a GXP 1x. However, I havent found anywhere whether the two sets are compatible, and that is the list of things that I need to but to make the conversion. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

If you just plan to change the crankset, that shouldn't be an issue with a 10-speed or 11-speed system (with 12-speed, that may be different because SRAM uses larger rollers on their flattop chains). The only parts you'd need are the crankset and bottom bracket.

Comment: So then I'm gonna try buying and fitting [this SM-BBR60](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800/SM-BBR60.html) botom bracket and this [Shimano GRX FC-RX600](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/FC-RX600-1.html) crankset.